# Generate Instagram Client Id/Access Token for more than 5 clients or Use Single Token/Id for all pages of one website

Tags: php, api, instagram, access-token

I went to add a new client at http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ and got this response:

---

> Sorry, you already registered the maximum number of clients. Delete an
>   existing client to continue.

---

I had five clients registered already.

Is there any way to increase the number of clients. or using one client/ access token for mulitple pages of same website. ***All the five clients I have created are subpages of same website(OAuth redirect_uri of the website) becuase I have given import functionality at many pages**.* Is there a way one access token can be used for a complete website ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but if you are just accessing APIs, then Yes, you can use one client_id/access_token to access APIs from multiple pages and also multiple websites.

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot to mention, I am using this to import images from instagram to my website. And as I do so, I had to generate cliend_id and access tokens for each url/page

Comment: you dont have to one client_id can get images for multiple pages or websites or apps

Comment: These are the OAuth redirect_uri that are creating problem, I have registered by website, but for each redirection url I have to generate a new token

Comment: when u make oauth, add a url param say "&page=p1", this will be in url param when u get redirect, use it to check and internally redirect to different page, so all redirect will go to one page and then your server should redirect to different page based on &page= param